# Can I see the Logcat on the Android Phone itself, without connecting it to the computer?

Tags: android, logcat

If yes, then how?
Does Logcat also log events like starting time of application on its own, or the application has to use something like Log.v(App_name,message) at the start of the application?

Answer (score 5):

exactly Sashi : aLogCat is basical, but if you want your own reader, there is a special permission for this : [Read_logs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_LOGS).

The least you can see is an entry from the ActivityManager : looking like this approx.

```
- Timestamp - INFO/ActivityManager(7703): Starting: Intent {act=android.intent.action.MAIN
cat= [android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]cmp=com.lemonde.androidapp/.SplashActivity 
bnds=[5,553][115,671] } from pid 7786
```

and here is an [interesting tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/reading-logs-programatically)

Good luck !

Comment: can i get undead tutorial link?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few applications in the market that will let you view the logcat on the phone.  One example is [aLogCat](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat).  Also, I'm pretty sure that it does log a message when the application gets loaded (certainly for the activity being started.

Comment: Thank you, but aLogCat does not keep a timestamp. I want a way to find the time my application started and closed.