# How to debug Android App in Exclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

Ok.
So while this isnt a programming question. 
I wanted to know how do people debug apps?
How do you view log cat, and where these exceptions are thrown etc?
And do I need to run the app on the emulator to see all the stuff, or is there a way to view this after running the app on my phone(while not being connected to the computer)

Links to plugins and tips would be really helpful, as im gonna start work on my next game, and while the first one works fine, had a lot of problems while debugging.

Comment: You can debug, see logcat in Eclipse on both emulator and real device (connected though). Is there anything above that that you want?

Comment: I dont know how to view it.
I keep reading stuff like type "this" in the command line.
Dont know where the command line is,or what they are referring to.

Comment: You mean adb? It's in \android-sdk\platform-tools folder in the location where you installed all your Android SDK files.

Comment: got it. gonna try it out, and get familiar with it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup: download the Android Developer Tools (ADT) plugin for Eclipse from here http://developer.android.com/tools/index.html

To debug:

1. Connect your phone to PC via USB
2. Open Eclipse, set breakpoints
   wherever you need
3. Run -> Debug to relaunch your app in debug mode
4. Use the Debug perspective, see:
   http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-projects.html

Comment: For this the app would need to run on the emulator or on the device(while connected to the computer)
If I run it directly on my device without conecting it to the computer), is there a way to view the logcat?

Comment: This question already has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376889/can-i-see-the-logcat-on-the-android-phone-itself-without-connecting-it-to-the-c